# Scipy fmin updating data inside a function

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem with my code. I don't know how to update the values of the variable `error` inside a function. The values only update outside the function.
Can somebody help me with this problem?

The idea of the code is to fit a model to my data `(x,y) = (mes1,pasajeros1)`. The model is a polynomial function plus a sine modulated by an exponential function.

`Error` is a vector, which is the difference between the data (`y` vector) and the fit (polynomial function plus sine modulated by a exponential of the previous iteration), with every iteration every component of the vector `error` has to be smaller.

This is the code:

```
def base_pol(x,N):
     M=np.ones(x.size)
     for i in range(1,N+1):
     M=np.vstack([M ,x**i])
     return M.T

def pol(x,theta):
    N=theta.size
    pol=base_pol(x,N-1)@theta
    return pol

def bestpolsin(theta, theta2, m):
    fpol = pol(mes1,theta)
    fsinexp = 0
    best_aic = 10000000
    best_bic = 10000000
    best_parametros = []

    def Fsinexp(x):
        Fsinexp = x[0]*(np.sin(x[1]*mes1+x[2]))*np.exp(x[3]*mes1)
        return Fsinexp

    def Jpolsin(x):
        j = 0.5*(error@error) - error@Fsinexp(x) + 0.5*(Fsinexp(x)@Fsinexp(x))
    return j 

    for i in range(m):
        error = pasajeros1 - fpol - fsinexp
        parametros = fmin(Jpolsin, theta2, args=(error,))
        fsinexp = Fsinexp(parametros)
        aic = AIC(4*(i+1), Jpolsin(parametros))
        bic = BIC(4*(i+1), Jpolsin(parametros))
        best_parametros.append(parametros) 
        if best_aic>aic:
           best_aic=aic
           r_1=i+1
        if best_bic>bic:
           best_bic=bic
           r_2=i+1
     p=r_1==r_2

     return aic, bic, r_1, best_parametros, p
```

Comment: Could you provide something like expected and actual values or trend of your variable "error" to make your point clearer?

Comment: Error is a vector, is the diference betwen the data (''y'' vector) and the fit (polinomial function plus a sin modulated by a exponential of the previous iteration), with every iteration every component of the vector ''error'' has to be smaller.

Comment: Args is supposed to be a tuple: `args=(error,)`.  But then your function needs to accept that argument: `Jpolsin(x, error)`.  I'd suggest experimenting with `fmin` with a simpler case, so you have a good idea of how to call it correctly.

Comment: @RafaelInostroza So you basically try to implement a [scipy curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) with your own script?

Comment: yes, using a sum of equal functions, but with different parameters.
I want to fit one term of the sum in every iteration, the idea is to fit the entire function sequentially